# How to add one file with classes third party library in to Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, composer, coding-standards

I have a single PHP file with some classes as a library. For example:

```
<?php

class addShipment
{
    public $packages; // przesylkaType
    public $id; // int
}

class addShipmentResponse
{
    public $retval; // addShipmentResponseItemType
}

class packageType
{
    public $guid;
    public $packageGuid;
    public $desc;
}
```

I think it would be good to add it in **lib/internal** folder and also I was thinking to put it in `composer.json` file like this:

```
"classmap": [
    "lib/internal/PathToFile/ApiClasses.php"
]
```

But I don't know if I should do it in module `composer.json` file or root one?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This library should follow PHP coding standard. You need to convert this library to the [Basic Coding Standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) and [Coding Style Guide](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/).

Because this library doesn't have its own composer json, so create a separate file for each class, put them directly in your custom module. See @Fabian Schmengler answer.

<del>Create a separate file for each class. Put all new files under `lib/internal` folder. Create composer json to define autoload standard.</del>

[image]

For example composer json:

```
{
    "name": "customlib/lib",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "Custom PHP Client Library",

    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "CustomLib\\Lib\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

<del>To recompile the composer autoloading files, run the following command in your Magento 2 root: `composer dumpautoload`</del>

- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/coding-standards/bk-coding-standards.html

Comment: Thx. Is there any automated process to do this? There is like 300 classes in this file :(

Comment: Woa! A lot of files, which libary? You can give me the link? I need to see?

Comment: It's 300 classes in one file :/ legacy code from work can't share it :(

Comment: After adding by above method, I can we access that library class ?

Answer (score 1):

`lib/internal` is meant for core libraries (therefore **internal**)

If this is a third party library that does not come with its own `composer.json`, I'd recommend to put it into its own package/module where you can use the `classmap` feature. Structure the package like this without bothering about the directory structure of Magento:

```
+- composer.json
+- src
   +-ApiClasses.php
```

Then install it into your Magento project via composer.

Comment: What about adding the third party libraries under: `lib/external`?

Comment: I once added a 3rd party lib under lib/ next to internal, but I don't (yet) see what putting it into it's own package/module might improve, Thank's for the input